# (yet another) modify git history to add a very first commit

Tags: git, git-rebase

I am modifying someone else's (non-git) code. I downloaded the original, ensued my modifications, and jumped the gun and made the modified version my first commit. This was a mistake, I should have added the original downloaded code as my first commit.

Then to add insult to injury, I added the original code as a branch off of my first edit.. In other words it is a big mess now :(

In simple terms, what I have looks like the blue graph below. C5 is the actual original code, C1,C2-C6 are my gradual modifications (C4 is redundant). I'd rather have the green be my history.

[image]

Any ideas how to modify history to accomplish this?

Thanks many,

sly

Comment: i chopped off at C6 and onwards, but any future commits are of course supposed to follow as-is.

Comment: I wonder if it may just be cleaner to restore each commit to its own folder, and start from scratch with an `init` and then copy over each version and `commit` in the right order. It's not a git solution, but it's a workaround that may actually be quicker.

Comment: Thanks Randolph. I however am very interested in git solution in order to learn about it. (also there is an online -- but unshared -- mirror which I want to just push and be done with)

Comment: Fair enough. I am interested in the git solution too, just for academic reasons :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have done this completely at the command-line, but am going to insert screenshots from SourceTree to illustrate what's going on.

First get the first 7 or 8 digits of commit id (50da9c3) from the C5 commit and put in on your clipboard or in textedit or something - you'll need it later

For confirmation, Here is our starting state:

[image]

Here are the steps to get where you want:

Create a new non-rooted branch to start building commits off of named base

```
git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/base
```

Now remove all files and directories from git

```
git rm --cached -r .
```

Now that all the files are 'untracked' remove them from the local working directory

```
git clean -d --force
```

Now create a commit with nothing in it (this will be the commit on which everything else will be built).

```
git commit --allow-empty -m'Initial Commit'
```

Your tree should look like this now:

[image]

Now cherry pick the c5 commit (what you had on the clipboard)

```
git cherry-pick 50da9c3
```

[image]

Now re-root the master branch on to the base branch

```
git rebase --onto base --root master
```

[image]

Now you can delete the base and c4-c5 branches

```
git branch -d base
```

[image]

```
git branch -D c4-c5branch
```

[image]

Keep in mind the the 'Initial Commit' is an empty commit with no files, so don't be fooled.  The C5 commit is actually the first content based commit.

Comment: this was tremendously useful. Thank you!